# nginx ignoring Apache rewrite directive

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

My problem is like this:
- I now use nginx in front of Apache server wide meaning all my websites
- all the rewrites I have in the .htaccess file work perfect, except 1 and up so far noone managed to give me a solution

This is the .htaccess rule

```
 -------------
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.(html|htm)\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(html|htm)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
 -------------
```

This does the following:
- it redirects with a 301 http code from www.domain.com/index.html to www.domain.com
- it takes both index.html and index.htm

Now the thing is that this worked prior to installing nginx and works so far for index.htm.. it redirects properly.
But index.htm does not exist.

I tried the other way around and found out that if the file exists, the redirect WON'T happen.

Another weird thing that I found is the following: I also have mod_pagespeed installed from Google and when I access the URL with www.domain.com/index.html... the one that DOES NOT rewrite to /, this mod_pagespeed is... inactive.. meaning no changes occur in the source for instance....like that URL is not from the same normal requests.

Btw..in ssh when I issue the nginx command I get this:

```
nginx: [warn] duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:30
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 111.111.111.111:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 111.111.111.111:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 111.111.111.111:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 111.111.111.111:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 111.111.111.111:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

111.111.111.111 - fake ip

I've looked for the duplicate MIME.. can't find it there and the rest of the bind stuff...
not a clue.

If you guys have a clue I'd happily share a virtual mug of beer with you for a good piece of info.

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, nginx tries to listen on 80 port that already in use by apache. You should move apache to another port in case you want nginx to be frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) how do I do that without breaking stuff? edit the httpd.conf? I know there are ports there.

Comment: However the above is the least in the priority list.. the one I'm more concerned is the redirect that is not doing what it should.

Comment: I can't figure out why do you need `RewriteCond`. It looks like `RewriteRule` alone can do the job.

Comment: What error do you get accessing www.domain.com/index.html ? In apache's log? In browser?

Comment: No error.. that is the problem. :|

Answer (score -1):

This might help.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.(html|htm)\ HTTP/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(html|htm)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: nope :( it's like that URL.. ignores .htaccess completely. if I write some wrong lines in the .htaccess and access that URL the file is displayed.. if I check other URL's they fail with 502 like they should :|